# ArrayAdapter and ListView - my app crashing

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've spent reading and tweaking my code for a while now but it keeps crashing and I can't figure out why it's crashing. Can someone please point out where I am making the error. I am a noob to programming and Android development trying to understand the basics of ArrayAdapters and ListViews.

Here's my code: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.samplelistviewapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItems.add("hello");
        listItems.add("how do you do");
        listItems.add("Ca va");
        listItems.add("Bonjour");
        listItems.add("Toronto");
        listItems.add("hello");
        listItems.add("mississauga");
        listItems.add("computer");
        listItems.add("ipad");
        listItems.add("sky");
        listItems.add("hello");
        listItems.add("road");
        listItems.add("mountain");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here's my xml: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` gets executed in the constructor, before the call to `setContentView`. Since the view has not yet been loaded the requested view does not exist, returning `null`.

Move the `findViewById` to after the call to `setContentView`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.